# Combobox list is transparant after populate

Tags: extjs, combobox

I try to use a combobox in my formpanel. This works and the store is loading when you click on the combobox. But when it is loaded it is not showing a background.I try to build and refresh the app but no matter what i do or what theme i use it keeps showing it transparant.

This is my combobox

```
{
            xtype: 'combobox',
            name: 'type',
            anchor: '100%',
            fieldLabel: 'Type',
            displayField:'naam',
            valueField:'id',
            multiSelect: false,
            editable: false,
            store: 'ProductenGroepComboTypeJsonStore',
            listConfig: {
                        loadingText: null,
                        loadMask: false
                    }
        }
```

the store is this

```
Ext.define('JustRent.store.ProductenGroepComboTypeJsonStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'JustRent.model.ProductenGroepComboTypeModel',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'ProductenGroepComboTypeJsonStore',
            model: 'JustRent.model.ProductenGroepComboTypeModel',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'resources/json/productType.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }

});
```

this is how it looks like

[image: list without a background]

Comment: It might be layout or combobox height issue .Provide height to your combo box once and check.Remove all other components and check the list whether it is still displaying transparent or not.If not it is your layout issue,if so it is your component issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is ideal for you but you can define the css classes to apply to your list and try to do a workaround that way

```
listConfig: {
                    xtype: 'boundlist',
                    baseCls: 'your-css-list',
                    maxHeight: 200,
                    itemCls: 'your-css-list-item'
                }
```

Hope it helps :)